# Save node after payment success

Tags: php, paypal, drupal-modules, payment-gateway, ubercart

In my projects, whenever an authenticated user creates new content (a page) they should redirect to paypal for payment when they click the save button. Once payment is successful, the page can be saved; otherwise it should not save.

Does Drupal have any modules for doing something like this?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Where specifically do you have problems? What have you tried?

Comment: In my project User can add Advertisement. So i have created one content type called Advertisement. Whenever Authenticated user want to add new Advertisement they can create but when they click save button its should goto paypal. once payment done advertisement can publish otherwise that advertisement should not.

So drupal have any modules or need idea for doing this??

Answer (score 0):

hook_node_presave should be should be what you are looking for:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7